# Open multiple links in a window and another multiple links in another window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Is there any way to open a bunch of 3-4 links in a browser **window** and another bunch of 3-4 links in **another window**.

For Example.

Links A = {"facebook.com","instagram.com","twitter.com"}
Should open in browser window (**chrome**)

and

Links B = {"google.com","yahoo.com","bing.com"}
Should open in same browser (**chrome**) but another window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Process.Start` method with `/new-window` argument which will enforce what it says as the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "/new-window facebook.com instagram.com twitter.com");
```

the above will open all links in one window with multiple tabs.

so in your case what you need is something like the following:

```
var A = new string[] { "facebook.com", "instagram.com", "twitter.com" };
var B = new string[] { "google.com", "yahoo.com", "bing.com" };
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", " /new-window " +  string.Join(" ", A));
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", " /new-window " + string.Join(" ", B));
```

Comment: **Thank you** so much. you saved my life :P